How do I remove the console window in a C++ application in Visual Studio?
I have a GLFW and OpenGL program in C++ Visual Studio with a window. The console window popping up whenever I run the program is annoying. How do I remove it? I'm on windows but I don't want to make it windows specific, it should be able to run on other OS's.

What's the value of the /SUBSYSTEM option in your project? Check under project's Property Pages -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem.

It is set to Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE).

Well, then set it to Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS). To quote from the docs above: "WINDOWS – The application doesn't require a console, probably because it creates its own windows for interaction with the user."

When I do that it gives me this error:
Severity Code Description File Line Suppression State Details Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) D:\repos\Snail Engine\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj) 1   

Set the entry point symbol (the /ENTRY option) as well: under project's Property Pages -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Entry Point, type mainCRTStartup.

oh, thank you so much!

@AseedSecond "I'm on windows but I don't want to make it windows specific, it should be able to run on other OS's" - you can't run the same executable file on multiple platforms. So you have to tailor your project to compile a separate executable for each platform. And on Windows, you would use the WINDOWS subsystem to make your Windows-specific executable avoid the console window.
